# sorting elements in dom based on text through javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

following is my html structure:

```
<div class="qotd">
    <div class="inner">
                <p id="19001"><span>text1</span>

                  <br>
                  <span class="uptext">1</span>
                  <img class="im upimg" src="http://www.deratus.com/pictures/2010/02/Up-championed-to-win-oscar.jpg">
                  <img class="im downimg" src="http://www.freeclipartnow.com/d/40224-1/arrow-blue-rounded-down.jpg">
                  <span class="downtext">2</span>
                </p>
            </div>
</div>
```

the above structure is repeated 8 times with different numbers.

i have ahref tags acting as buttons to sort the `p` based on the `uptext` and `downtext`

```
<a href="#" id="pos" class="btn">Sort by upvotes</a>
    <br /> <br />
          <a href="#" id="neg" class="btn">Sort by downvotes</a>
    <br /> <br />
```

i wrote the following jquery to sort the paragraphs based on their upvotes or downvotes:

```
$(function){
$("#pos").click(function(e) {
    console.log("up");
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.inner').sort(function(a, b) {

            return parseInt($('.uptext', b).text(), 10) - parseInt($('.uptext', a).text(), 10) ;
        }).appendTo('div.qotd');
    });

    $("#neg").click(function(e) {
      console.log("down");
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.inner').sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseInt($('downtext', b).text(), 10) - parseInt($('.downtext', a).text(), 10);
        }).appendTo('div.qotd');
    });
}
```

***The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Escf3/2/)***
Despite all the above i do not get the correct result, where am i going wrong?

Comment: what result do you get, is it sorted in the wrong order, or is there an error thrown?

Comment: have updated the fiddle, check it.

Comment: @user902620 Your jsfiddle throws an error that stops it from running. Check your developer console to see the error.

Comment: updated the edited link.

Comment: `$('downtext', b).text()` should be `$('.downtext', b).text()`... then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your `$(function() {` *.ready handler* and in one of your `.downtext` selectors. I fixed the sorting algo slightly into

```
return +$(b).find('.uptext').text() - +$(a).find('.uptext').text();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Escf3/3/

It is still a kinda questionable operation tho. You're doing a lot of queries/DOM crawling each time you call those sorting functions + jQuery overhead.

Comment: could you please explain the - + thing, i could not understand, how this sort and selector is actually working.

Comment: and whats wrong with using: return parseInt($('.uptext', b).text(), 10) - parseInt($('.uptext', a).text(), 10) ;

Comment: @user902620: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29). It's just a shorter way of writing it. `$(a, b)` calls `$(b).find(a)` internally, so it is often preferred to use this form directly.

Comment: @user902620: there is nothing wrong with using `parseInt()`, but its kinda verbose and slow'ish for your purpose here. `+` will "cast" a string into its numerical version (if we are dealing with a number) otherwise it returns `NaN`.